# Nested sequence intersection is empty

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Show  by  providing  a  concrete  example  that  the  intersection  of  a  nested  sequence  of  closed(but not necessarily bounded) intervals may be empty

Comment: So... no thoughts whatsoever? The parenthetical hint is a pretty good one.

Comment: Hint: Choose as first interval $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: This isn't always true of course, so you need an example.  If the examples are bounded then the sup of each set is in the set and the sequence of sups would be bounded below and so the inf of sups would exist and be in the intersection.  So we need a bunch of nested closed unbounded sets where the interiors "just keep vanishing".

Comment: @fleablood so if the first interval is [1, infinity), then since there is no sup, we can derive there is no intersection?

Comment: Well, you can't have an intersection with just one set.   You need a more sets.  You need $.... S_3 \subset S_2 \subset S_1$.  $[1, \infty)$ is a really good choice for $S_1$.  So what is $S_2$? Find sets that are nested but whose intersection "vanish" rather than "condense".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_n=[n,\infty)$. Then $A_n$ is closed and $A_1\supset \cdots\supset A_n\cdots$. We can prove that 
$$I=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\varnothing$$
For any $x\in I, \:x\in A_n \:\forall n$, but this is impossible because there is always a $N>x$ and thus $x\notin A_N$. So $I=\varnothing$.